# Basics of dynamic loading a drop down box

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I'm new to php/ajax and to an extent sql. I'm trying to add a dynamic drop down box which when select will either load up another drop down box with dates or another text box. Can someone point me towards some simple examples that are not very confusing. I understand that ajax is best for this.

script

```
  function showfield(name){
 if(name=='byreturn')document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
 else document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
 }

if(name=='forwardorder')document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
else document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
}


  function hidefield() {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
}
```

---

page

```
       <tr><td> <body onload='hidefield()'>
                Choose Delivery Type </td>
               <td> <select name = 'elementtype1'id='elementtype1' onchange='showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
                        <option value='forwardorder'>Forward Order</option>
                        <option value='byreturn'>By Return</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td>

                        <div id='div1'>Enter By Return Date<input type='text''name='whatever1' />
                        </div>

                        <div id='div2'>
                        <td>Capacity</td>
                        <td><select name='deliveryDate'>
                        $listCapacityDates = $cid->ListCapacity();
                        foreach($listCapacityDates as $x) {
                        <option value='" . $x[cap] . "'</option>;
                        </div>
                        </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple

```
<select name="first" onChange="populateNextBox(this)">
 <options value="1">Microsoft</options>
 <options value="2">Oracle</options>
</select>

<div id="populate"></div>
```

When user select the value from the drop down

**required java script function**

```
 function populateNextBox(e) {
      alert(e.value); //will print the selected value
      //used jquery for populating data
      $.post('ajax/test.php?id='+e.value, function(data) {
          $('#populate').html(data);
      });
    }
```

**//Your ajax/test.php will create the content for the dropdown**

Comment: i've attempted the following but it will not work. If chosen forward opens up another drop down box, if chosen by forward it opens up a txt box.

Comment: @user969733 You can add more boxes ,or anything you want like these fashion

Comment: What is wrong with this , you need some debugging as well through the code

Comment: its not showing displaying the drop down list if i select the second option, it shows both!

Comment: It should be like this if(name=='forwardorder')document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
else document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";  You are showing div1 and hising same div1 , what is this ?

Comment: i've stored the fields in a div so it hides the fields if either isnt chosen